# Validate user name and password in IdentityServer4 in implicit flow

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

How can user name and password be validated in `Implicit` flow? I tried adding a custom `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` validator, but it is not calld when I set a breakpoint there:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())

    .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
    ;
```

The validator:

```
public class ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
{

    public ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator()
    {
    }

    public async Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

When I look at source code of IdentityServer4, into class `TokenRequestValidator`, it seems `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` validator is called only in the `Password` flow.

When I tried to add `IExtensionGrantValidator`, which is the default validator (including `Implicit`), it is also not called.

How can user name and password be validated in the `Implicit` flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution, the username/password validation is not part of the authorization flow, it is done directly in the Controller of the login page, in the sample 7 it is done in the `AccountController`.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // validate username/password against in-memory store
    if (_users.ValidateCredentials(model.Username, model.Password))
    {
        ...
    }
```

It is enough to replace this piece of code with validation against a real user store instead of the default `TestUserStore`.